# Customising std::shared_ptr or boost::shared_ptr to throw an exception on NULL dereference

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, shared-ptr, libc++

I have a few projects that use `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` extensively (I can convert to either implementation soon enough, if there is a good answer to this question for one, but not the other).  The Boost implementation uses Boost.Assert to avoid returning in the case of encountering an empty (NULL) pointer in `operator*` or `operator->` at runtime; while the libc++ implementation seems to lack any check.

While of course the validity of a `shared_ptr` should be checked before use, a large, mixed-paradigm codebase leads me to want to try an exception-throwing variation; as most of the code is relatively exception-aware and will at most fail to a high-level but resumable state, rather than `std::terminate()` or segfault.

How should I best customise these accessors while maintaining the robustness of `shared_ptr`?  It seems that encapsulating `shared_ptr` in a `throwing_shared_ptr` may be the best option, but I'm wary of breaking the magic.  Am I best off copying the Boost source and just changing the `ASSERT`s to an appropriate `throw` statement?

---

The actual type name used everywhere for the appropriate `smart_ptr<T>` type is a typedef expanded from a macro; i.e. `ForwardDeclarePtr(Class)` expands to something like:

```
class Class;
typedef boost::smart_ptr<Class> ClassPtr;
```

Everything passes, takes, or stores a `ClassPtr` - so I can replace the underlying type pretty freely; and I suspect this alleviates the potential slicing/hiding issue.

Comment: You could use a small library I wrote called [throwing_ptr](https://github.com/rockdreamer/throwing_ptr). It wraps std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr, adding exceptions in dereference operators if the pointer is not initialised. It also has both make_shared and make_unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's really no "magic" in `std::shared_ptr<T>` that would be removed if you wrapped it inside a custom class that would throw an exception when dereferencing a `NULL` shared pointer.  So I don't see why that approach wouldn't work, as long as your new wrapper-class follows all the semantics of the `std::shared_ptr<T>` type.

BTW, you could also take a slightly different approach, and that is create a wrapper-class that simply won't allow others to pass `NULL` pointers to the wrapped `std::shared_ptr<T>` data-member in the first-place.  Basically it would be a class that would enforce the `std::make_shared<T>` idiom in its constructor.  I'm not sure, based on the workings of your code if this is possible, but it's another way to circumvent the problem using a RAII approach rather than throwing exceptions.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it's a bit easier to explain the design, safety, and usage of the encapsulation in comments (classes have `shared_ptr` members all the time). @KevinBallard is also correct, though.

Answer (score 5):

Just subclass `std::shared_ptr` into `throwing_shared_ptr`, override those two methods, and have them assert and call through to `std::shared_ptr`'s impl. This should work fine as long as you use `throwing_shared_ptr` everywhere instead of slicing it to a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Even slicing won't be a catastrophic problem as long as the derived type doesn't add any data members.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Correct, but it will remove the throwing nature. Of course, if your value is typed as `std::shared_ptr` then I guess you should expect that anyway.

Comment: @KevinBallard This may actually be the bigger issue than the question; what to do if something expects a plain `shared_ptr` - there is at least one case of 3rd-party code which does so.  I doubt throwing an exception through said library would be *worse* than `std::terminate()` or `SIGSEGV` - but it does merit serious consideration.

Comment: Disregard above, the library code would of course take parameters or store them in the `shared_ptr` of its own choosing; as mentioned, potentially slicing at the call site, but not changing the semantics of internal code.