# How to make shared_ptr wrapper class work with make_shared

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

This question extends [Customising std::shared_ptr or boost::shared_ptr to throw an exception on NULL dereference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452565).

I want a class that behaves like shared_ptr, but that throws an exception when dereferencing a nullptr. In above's question, it was recommended to create a wrapper class that contains a shared_ptr, and to have that wrapper throw the exception.

However, I'd also like to continue using make_shared. Is there some way to make make_shared work with my (or any) wrapper class of shared_ptr? Something that works along the lines of

```
checked_shared_ptr<MyClass> csp = make_checked_shared<MyClass>(...);
```

Comment: I guess inherit from `shared_ptr` and provide constructors and assignment operators (for copy and move) that accept a `shared_ptr&`.

Comment: Or do the same with the wrapper? And maybe specialize the make_shared for this new type?

Comment: @martin_pr, you can't write a partial specialization of a function template, you'd need to overload it (in your own namespace).

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yup, fair enough, my bad...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Add a suitable constructor

The easiest solution would be to add a constructor to `template<class T> class checked_shared_ptr` so that it can be initialized with a `std::shared_ptr<T>`, this would effectively make the below compile (and do what is expected).

```
checked_shared_ptr<MyClass> csp = std::make_shared<MyClass> (...);
```

---

#### Sample Implementation

```
template<class T>
struct checked_shared_ptr {

  template<
    class U,
    class = decltype (std::shared_ptr<T> (std::shared_ptr<U> {}))
  > checked_shared_ptr (std::shared_ptr<U> const& src)
    : _sptr (src)
  { }

  // ...

  T& operator* () {
    if (_sptr)
      return *_sptr;

    throw std::runtime_error ("nullptr");
  }

  // ...

  std::shared_ptr<T> _sptr;
};
```

```
checked_shared_ptr<MyClass> csp = std::make_shared<MyClass> ();
```

<sub>**Note**</sub>

The usage of `decltype(std::shared_ptr<T> (std::shared_ptr<U>))` is so that the constructor only takes part in overload resolution if one can convert `U*` to `T*`.

- [**cppreference.com** - `shared_ptr` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)